# How can I resume connection between SQL Server and physical files after hard disk disabling?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server

I have problems with database after reconnection Hard Disk:

Reproducing:

1. .Net application works with DB.
2. Disconnect Hard disk with physical files (db.mdf db.ldf).
3. Make any request to the database (of course we will have an exception like "Unable to open the physical file").
4. Reconnect Hard disk.
5. Any query to the database in the future will throw an exception "Unable to open the physical file".

How can I recover connection with physical files without rebooting the SQL Server?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by disconnect from hard drive? Detach database?

Comment: No, the hard drive (with .mdf files) is temporarily unavailable without any detaching.

Comment: Probably better asked on DBA.stackexchange.com

Comment: @BlackICE instead of telling them to ask at a different StackExchange site, please just vote to close as off-topic so it can be migrated. Now we have [two copies of this question that will eventually have to be merged](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47536/how-can-i-resume-connection-between-sql-server-and-physical-files-after-hard-dis).

Answer (score 0):

Lets start saying that you are in a very bad shape and you should check your physical server ASAP.

IMO, the best thing to do is

**backup the files `as-is` just in case you can't do anything else**

then one of the following options

- restart `SQL Server service`
- delete the **broken database**
- restore restore back ups to the latest transaction point

If the above is impossible.

- restart `SQL Server service`
- hope that things will work

Comment: Requests are made to the database are not frequently (about once a minute).
At the moment, the problem is solved in two requests (SET Offline and SET Online) but I think there is not very good decision.

Comment: is this happening often? Still IMO you should check your server is healthy

Comment: It happens from time to time because the database is actually located on the remote disk.

Comment: As far as I remember, that is against MS requirement, (possible but strongly not recommended). why can't you move to a local drive?

Comment: I know about it but it's customer needs..(((

Comment: so, looks like a `feature` due to design.  don't think that you are going to get much further in this site.